# Is $A := \{ a \in \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } (\forall b \in [0,1]) [ a \ge b \Rightarrow a \ge 2b ] \}$ equal to the interval $[2,\infty)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

We're interested in determining the set

$$A := \{ a \in \mathbb{R}  \text{ such that }  (\forall b \in [0,1]) [ a \ge b \Rightarrow a \ge 2b  ] \} $$

The answer seems be the interval $[2,+\infty)$.

any ideas on how to prove it rigorously?

Comment: How do you generally prove that two sets are equal?

Comment: If $x \in A$ then $x \ge 2*1$ and $1\in [0,1]$.  If $x\ge 2$ and $b \in [0,1]$ then $x \ge 2 \ge 2b$..... so.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complement of your set
$$\mathbb{R} \setminus A = \{a \in \mathbb{R} : \exists b \in [0,1], b \leq a < 2b\} = \bigcup_{b \in [0,1]} [b,2b)$$

Since $[0, 2(0)) = \emptyset,$ we may refine this slightly to
$$\mathbb{R} \setminus A = \bigcup_{0 < b \leq 1} [b,2b)$$

It's now perhaps simpler to see that **[show this]**
$$\bigcup_{0 < b \leq 1} [b,2b) = (0, 2)$$
from which we conclude
$$A = \mathbb{R}\setminus\left(\mathbb{R}\setminus A\right) = (-\infty, 0] \cup [2, +\infty)$$

Comment: why did you took into consideration the interval $(-\infty, 0]$? $b$ is a positive number smaller than $1$.

Comment: @Iuli The work I've shown shows that $\mathbb{R} \setminus A = (0,2)$ and the complement of this inside $\mathbb{R}$ includes $(-\infty, 0].$  At that point, $b$ is irrelevant.

Comment: @Iuli, Implication $p \Rightarrow q$ is true also when $p$ is false. In such case, this implication is called 'vacuously true'. The interval $(-\infty, 0]$ comes from this consideration.

Comment: It is clear for me what you did. For me it is not correct to use "conclude" word as long as the conclusion is $2, /infty]$.